# How can I define a global variable with Ionic 3?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

i have a function on my home.ts folder that name `displayMap()`. I want to use the pos variable on other functions.

I try make this a global variable but there is something wrong and can not do that on my way.

I defined a globalPos variable like the following code.

```
export class HomePage {

  globalPos: any;
```

And try to save the pos value to globalPos with the following code.

```
displayMap(){
        let pos = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };
        let info = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

        that.globalPos = pos;
}
```

displayMap() function.

```
displayMap() {

    let that = this;


    let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.106334, 29.510615);

    let mapOptions = {
      center: latLng,
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      zoom: 15,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    };

    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
        let pos = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };
        let info = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

        that.globalPos = pos;

        info.setContent('you are here!');
        info.setPosition(pos);
        info.open(that.map);

        that.map.setCenter(pos);
      })
    }
  }
```

Comment: where and how you are calling displayMap() method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The case here is that you're not using [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) so inside `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` it'll be block scoped to that function and it'll not have access to the global scope.

Try changing the code for that one:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
  // YOUR CODE...
  this.globalPos = pos;
});
```

Hope this helps.